# How to create an azure container instance using a yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have a full CLI command in order to create an Azure Container Instance. Creating the instance from that command works fine. Now I am looking at place all those command parameters inside a yaml file.

I have check the follwoing link which help me started :
[Mount Azure files volume to container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files)

The questions I have is as below :

1 - In my command I need to get the image from my Azure Container registry, for which we need to pass the server name and password. How to define this entry in a yaml file ?

2 - I have a set of environment to be set, in which syntax should I set them ?

Thanks for your help
regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - In my command I need to get the image from my Azure Container
> registry, for which we need to pass the server name and password. How
> to define this entry in a yaml file ?

You specify the image registry credentials in your YAML file by using the `ImageRegistryCredentials` property

```html
imageRegistryCredentials: # Credentials to pull a private image
  - server: string
    username: string
    password: string
```

> 2 - I have a set of environment to be set, in which syntax should I
> set them ?

Here is the syntax to initialize environment variables

```html
environmentVariables:
      - name: string
        value: string
        secureValue: string
```

Here is the YAML reference Azure documentation for [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables#yaml-deployment)